# Using a stepper motor with an undersized power supply

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor

Is it possible to run a Nema 42 stepper motor 110HZ150-210 with 36V at slow speed and 15N.m load (its holding torque is 21 N.m)? If it is possible then how?

The specs of the motor:

- Step Angle: 1.8°
- Current /phase: 6.5 A
- Resistance /phase: 0.8 Ω
- Inductance /phase: 15 mH
- Holding Torque: 21 N.m
- leads: 6 wires

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if the motor needs 6.5A, and you give only 0.5A, then it won't move.

Comment: My driver modules set the current, so I simply run a lower voltage and current.

Comment: @kartman So I just need a driver that sets the current? Do such drivers have a specific name?

Comment: @tlfong01. I was wondering if there is a way to supply the 6.5 amps at lower voltage that's all.

Comment: Leadshine DM542 or TB6600 for example.

Comment: What's the current rating of your power supply? If the current rating is high enough, it'll work, and if the current rating is too low, it won't work.

Comment: @nour hashem, (1) Well, from the spec, I think you need a power supply of 36V with at least 6.5A. (2) For DM542 microstepping driver, you can set lower current, but not higher than 6.5A, because the max current is 36/R = 6.5A. (3) Reference: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/561492/driving-step-motors-using-microstep-drivers-with-teensy-4.